# C# difference between two dates where one ends with a Z?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two dates

```
DateTime date1Z = DateTime.Parse("2014-05-22 23:39:29Z");
DateTime date1ZKind = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-22 23:39:29Z"), DateTimeKind.Utc);

DateTime date2 = DateTime.Parse("2014-05-22 23:39:29");
DateTime date2Kind = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-22 23:39:29"), DateTimeKind.Utc);

Console.WriteLine(date1Z);
Console.WriteLine(date1ZKind);
Console.WriteLine(date2);
Console.WriteLine(date2Kind);
```

Prints

```
23/05/2014 11:39:29 a.m.
23/05/2014 11:39:29 a.m.
22/05/2014 11:39:29 p.m.
22/05/2014 11:39:29 p.m.
```

Can someone explain whats going on here?

Comment: "Z" stands for [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), also known as "zulu time".

Comment: The fact that you're in New Zealand probably accounts for most of the explanation you need. Let me guess - you're currently 12 hours ahead of UTC?

Comment: Also note that `DateTime.SpecifyKind` does not translate/convert times, but only sets the `Kind` property (which is read-only property) while leaving the date/time value unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the suffix "Z" is date shorthand for saying that the Date-Time is "Zulu" time which is another word for UTC time. The first two dates are being parsed as UTC, while the last two are being parsed as whatever time is on the computer in question.

So to answer you question of what is going on: the latter two dates are being offset by your local time, which is apparently +12:00 (plus twelve hours), while the first two are not (as they are marked as "Zulu" or UTC time).

Answer (score 1):

You live in New Zealand, which is +12 over UTC.  That matches the date difference you are experiencing.  As mentioned, the Z stands for UTC.